# Adding styles to mvc application

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm new to ASP/MVC programming. I want to add styles from [jquit](http://jquit.com/builder/#gcc=ffffff&gcb=d4d4d4&gct=525252&gci=d4d4d4&pcc=d4d4d4&acb=525252&o=ffffff&ghc=3399ff&ght=ffffff&ghi=ffffff&gdc=d4d4d4&gdb=d4d4d4&gdt=525252&tdc=3399ff&tdb=3399ff&tdt=ffffff&tdi=ffffff&ddc=d4d4d4&ddb=d4d4d4&ddt=525252&pxd=000000&asc=3399ff&ast=ffffff&goc=66B3FF&gob=66B3FF&got=ffffff&toc=66B3FF&tob=66B3FF&tot=ffffff&toi=ffffff&doc=66B3FF&dob=66B3FF&dot=ffffff&pxa=525252&gac=3399ff&gab=3399ff&gat=ffffff&tac=ffffff&tab=d4d4d4&tat=525252&tai=d4d4d4&dac=3399ff&dab=3399ff&dat=ffffff&dic=d4d4d4&dib=3399ff&dit=ffffff&gic=efdca9&gib=efdca9&git=525252&gii=525252&ec=c31d1d&eb=c31d1d&et=ffffff&ei=ffffff) and [a jquery-ui-themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#!zThemeParams=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). I tried copy-pasting the script and css files and refer them in the cshtml file. But, the views are not rendering. Clearly I'm doing something wrong. How can I get the styles to work?

Thank you

I created a new application using internet template of mvc4. Then I downloaded the jMetro template from one of the above sites. I pasted the contents into "../../Content/jquery-ui.css" and "../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" folders, which, I included in Registration.cshtml file.

Comment: how are we supposed to help, show your code you tried

Comment: Show the codes that you tried, or how you did it and what went wrong. That way you will get more help

Answer (score 0):

Use the section in your view i.e.

```
@section myScript{
<script type="text/javascript" src='path'/>
}
```

and in your _Layout.cshtml page, render the section on  area by using:

```
<head>
@RenderSection("myScript", false)
</head>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the way I had done. Not rendering in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to render your scripts and styles by razor,

`@Scripts.Render("Your path")
@Styles.Render("Your path")`.

And use the relative paths "~/Content/jquery-ui.css".

Comment: @Anoop.P.A Are you using bundles in rendering the files? Try to provide your view file with the style and script rendering.

Comment: I tried adding to the bundles as well as referencing them directly.